# javascript get id of "commonAncestorContainer"

Tags: javascript, range

So I feel like I'm a bit out of my league here. But here's what I want to do.

Basically, I want to have a user select part of text within in a paragraph (which may contain many elemnts (i.e. `<span>` and `<a>`) to return the value of the id attribute of that paragraph. Here's what I thinking.

```
function getParaID() //function will be called using a mouseUp event
{
var selObj = window.getSelection();
var selRange = selObj.getRangeAt(0); //btw can anyone explain what this zero means
var paraElement = selRange.commonAncestorContainer;
var paraID = paraElement.getAttribute;

return paraID;
 }
```

What do you think? Am I close?

Comment: Does it work? `paraID` will be a reference to the `getAttribute` function which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The selection range's `commonAncestorContainer` property may be a reference to a text node, or a `<span>` or `<a>` element or `<body>` element, or whatever else you may have in your page. That being the case, you need to work up the DOM tree to find the containing `<p>` element, if one exists. You also need to be aware that IE < 9 does not support `window.getSelection()` or DOM Range, although it is possible to do what you want quite easily in IE < 9. Here's some code that will work in all major browsers, including IE 6:

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/44Juf/

Code:

```
function getContainingP(node) {
    while (node) {
        if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.tagName.toLowerCase() == "p") {
            return node;
        }
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
}

function getParaID() {
    var p;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var selObj = window.getSelection();
        if (selObj.rangeCount > 0) {
            var selRange = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
            p = getContainingP(selRange.commonAncestorContainer);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        p = getContainingP(document.selection.createRange().parentElement());
    }
    return p ? p.id : null;
}
```

Regarding the `0` passed to `getRangeAt()`, that is indicating which selected range you want. Firefox supports multiple selected ranges: if you make a selection and then hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and make another selection, you will see you now have two discontinous ranges selected, which can be accessed via `getRangeAt(0)` and `getRangeAt(1)`. Also in Firefox, selecting a column of cells in a table creates a separate range for each selected cell. The number of selected ranges can be obtained using the `rangeCount` property of the selection. No other major browser supports multiple selected ranges.

Answer (score 2):

You're quite close.  If all you want is the id of the parent element, then you should replace your `paraElement.getAttribute` with `paraElement.id`, like:

```
var paraID = paraElement.id;
```

Regarding the parameter to `getRangeAt()`, it is specifying the index of the selection range to return, and it's only really relevant to controls that allow discontinuous selections.  For instance, a `select` box in which the user can use `ctrl + click` to select several arbitrary groups of rows simultaneously.  In such a case you could use the parameter to step from one selected region to the next.  But for highlighting text within a paragraph you should never have a discontinuous selection and thus can always pass `0`.  In essence it means that you're asking for "the first selected region".

Also note that if your interface allows the user's selection to span multiple paragraphs then your `commonAncestorContainer` may not be a paragraph, it might also be whatever element it is that contains all of your paragraph tags.  So you should be prepared to handle that case.

**Edit:**

After playing with this a bit, here is my suggestion:  http://jsfiddle.net/vCsZH/

Basically, instead of relying on `commonAncestorContainer` this code applies a `mouseDown` and a `mouseUp` listener to each paragraph (in addition to the one already applied to the top-level container).  The listeners will, in essence, record the paragraphs that the selection range starts and ends at, making it much simpler to reliably work out which paragraph(s) are selected.

If ever there was a case in favor of using dynamic event binding through a framework like jQuery, this is it.

Comment: You're a little off with your `getRangeAt()` explanation. `window.getSelection()` can only be used for user selections within regular web page content, not form elements, and in particular, not `<select>` elements. Also, it is possible in Firefox to select multiple different ranges by using the Ctrl key, or by selecting a column of cells in a table, which is what the `getRangeAt()` parameter is used for. No other major browser supports this.

Comment: @Tim - Thanks, the documentation that I found was a bit vague.  So if Firefox is the only browser that will ever have multiple selections, why does `getRangeAt()` support the parameter at all?  Is it that other browsers are *supposed* to support this feature but don't, or was the parameter added solely for the benefit of Firefox?

Comment: @aroth: Mozilla was the first browser to have the `Selection` API and I think always supported multiple ranges in the table case at least, hence the parameter's always been there. Other browsers have since come along and copied the API for compatibility, and now it's being standardized by WHATWG. It has the advantage of allowing for non-Mozilla browsers to add multiple selected range support without changing their API, although I don't think any of them are planning on adding it any time soon.