# Cant get container of selected text (jsfiddle available)

Tags: javascript

Lets assume I have some html like this:

```
  <div id='fooBar' contenteditable='true'>Hello <span class="test">World</span></div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
var fooBar = document.getElementById('fooBar');

fooBar.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer)
});
```

**Question:** Why wont It get the actual container named test? I cant figure out why this wont work. I even tried it with selection.anchorNode.parentElement. Nothing works. Now when looking at the internal architecture of the object I get from window.getSelection() then I dont see the span element listed as a property.  What am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/w7bfmLqd/1/

Comment: This would help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897187/javascript-get-id-of-commonancestorcontainer

Comment: he Range.commonAncestorContainer read-only property returns the deepest — or furthest down the document tree — Node that contains both boundary points of the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get this working using this:

```
var fooBar = document.getElementById('fooBar');

fooBar.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(window.getSelection().focusNode.parentElement);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w7bfmLqd/2/

Comment: But why the heck doesnt it work with anchorNode and commonAncestorContainer? Weird right? lol

Comment: I mean especially specifying getRangeAt(0). should have made things clear for the interpreter

Comment: Weird it doesnt work on  my side. My chrome version is fine. Maybe I need a reinstall. So weird

Comment: I feel so dumb having posted this question. Im sure it has to do with my chrome then because it works on firefox. my chrome is up to date though

Comment: Using chrome here, possibly a plugin? Anyway don't worry, happens to everyone